# Is there a way to remotely disable a domain laptop (SurfaceBook)

Tags: windows-10, windows-domain, microsoft-surface, domain-security

Our company has (*had* at the moment) a SurfaceBook that was with an employee when he was terminated. It's a part of our domain, but of course he can still sign into it when it's not in contact with the domain server as a local domain account gets created. Is there any way that I can disable it remotely?

Comment: Did you have any other remote-disablement tools installed in the laptop, e.g. some anti-theft software?

Comment: Even if you had the tools installed on the device.  If the employee can log into the device, they can Reset the device, which result in a fresh installation of Windows 10 which they would have complete and total control over.  My suggestion is if the employee has company propery, get local law enforcement involved, since your company will be able to prove ownership of the device and the employee won't.  Without the tools  I described, installed on the devie before you lost control over the device, then what you want is simply not posisble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you installed some remote wipe software like Prey on the Surface prior to it leaving, you cannot wipe/lock the device unless it connects to your network again. At that point, you could remotely wipe the device via something like SCCM.

At this point, the issue is damage control.

1. What passwords and accounts did they have access to?

All passwords he had access to should be changed as soon as possible, as well as any local account passwords (IE Local Admin).

2. What confidential information did they have on the laptop or access to?

There isn't too much you can do here, but if you suspect they took the info with them, you may want to seek legal advice even though most companies don't want to do this as it makes them look bad publicly.

Also, if the employee hasn't received their last paycheck, then you may be able to deduct the cost of the SurfaceBook from it.

Comment: I didn't word that terribly well apparently, I didn't want to disable his domain account - that's already done. I want to disable the entire device.

Comment: Right, I should have specified what I meant by changing accounts he had access to. If for example he worked in IT and had access to SSH passwords, or other credentials apart from his own account, they should be changed. Disabling the device is not possible now that has left, and won't be reconnecting to the network (even if it is domain joined).

Answer (score 1):

First, *disable* the user's AD account.  Steven Lee's answer of deleting the accounts is bad practice.  Have you ever seen a file in a shared folder that has no owner, just some random SID?  That happens when the account that created it was deleted.  Disabling accounts also allows you to reenable them in the future.  Sometimes, people get rehired and this allows you to easily give them back their documents, shares, etc.

Unless you have some sort of Mobile Device Management software, you cant lock him out of the device immediately.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my mistake. I've edited my original answer.